# Standalone and citation/cross-referencing from source document

Tags: bibliographies, standalone

How to cite or cross-reference an item from source document in a `standalone` document?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}

\begin{filecontents}{stdalone.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
   This is a test \cite{cref}.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

This is the source file.

This works here: \cite{cref}

But does not work here: \includestandalone{stdalone}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
   \bibitem{cref}
    A test reference.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The citation works in both cases for me. There is, however, a baseline alignment problem. Is this what your question refers to? If so, it happens with any ascender/descender.